# Syncing a random variable

Tags: javascript, random

I am currently making simple UI for my rock paper scissors game. I am using a random number for my getComputerChoice function which then is used to display an image and decide the outcome of the game. I tried setting the outcome of getComputerChoice to a variable but then I ran into the issue that the computer's choice would remain the same each time I ran a new game.

```
const model = {
  wins: 0,
  losses: 0,
  draws: 0,

  getCompChoice: function() {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    var choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

    var choice = choices[num];
    return choice;
  },

  gameLogic: function(player, computer) {
    if (player === false) {
      return alert("Please enter a valid guess");
    } else if (player === computer) {
      this.draws++;
      return "draw";
    } else if (
      (player === "rock" && computer === "paper") ||
      (player === "paper" && computer === "scissors") ||
      (player === "scissors" && computer === "rock")
    ) {
      this.losses++;
      return "lose";
    } else {
      this.wins++;
      return "win";
    }
  }
};
const view = {
  updateScore: function() {
    document.getElementById("wins").textContent = "Wins:" + " " + model.wins;
    document.getElementById("losses").textContent =
      "Losses:" + " " + model.losses;
    document.getElementById("draws").textContent = "Draws:" + " " + model.draws;
    return;
  },
  displayRollComputer: function() {
    var computer = document.getElementById("computer");
    computer.classList.remove("rock", "paper", "scissors");
    computer.classList.add(controller.compChoice);
    console.log(controller.compChoice);
  },
  displayRollUser: function() {
    var user = document.getElementById("user");
    user.classList.remove("rock", "paper", "scissors");
    user.classList.add(processPlayer());
  }
};
const controller = {
  compChoice: model.getCompChoice(),

  play: function() {
    model.gameLogic(processPlayer(), this.compChoice);
    view.updateScore();
    view.displayRollComputer();
    view.displayRollUser();
  }
};

// Helper Functions
function processPlayer() {
  const player = document.getElementById("guess").value;

  if (player === "rock" || player === "paper" || player === "scissors") {
    return player;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: You call `getCompChoice` once and once only?

Comment: No i call it in the displayRollComputer function aswell as play function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the `controller.compChoice` is not computed every time you call `gameLogic()`, but only once, during initialization. Change it to:

```js
const controller = {
  compChoice: model.getCompChoice(),

  play: function() {
    this.compChoice = model.getCompChoice(); <
    model.gameLogic(processPlayer(), this.compChoice);
    view.updateScore();
    view.displayRollComputer();
    view.displayRollUser();
  }
};
```

and everything should work as expected.

Comment: This doesnt work as I call compChoice in the displayRollComputer Function which displays an image of the computer choice. The issue is that compChoice result used for the image is not the same as the compChoice result used for the game outcome

Comment: Yes, I overlooked that. I've updated my answer to match this issue, now it's even less drastic.